# Is there any way to detect the browser's plugins other than deprecated navigator.plugins/mimeTypes?

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins, navigator

According to the latest MDN documentation, the method [navigator.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/plugins) and [the plugin object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Plugin) has been deprecated. How to detect plugins without them?

Comment: why do you need to detect plugins?

Comment: @JaromandaX Just for curiosity. I'm reading a JS book.